# jquery parse html in xml

Tags: jquery, xml, html-parsing

I have an xml file with html tags in it that I parse using jquery ajax.
I can get the text value without a problem. How do I get the html part within an element?

Edit: I tried wrapping the html in cdata but would rather have the xhtml within the xml.

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET",
                        url: "product.xml",
                        dataType: "xml",
                        success: function (xml) {

                            $(xml).find("product[productid=" + selection + "]").each(function () {
                                var $title = $(this).find("title").text();        //get title  
                                var $desc = $(this).find("description").html();          //get description  
                                //$('[nodeName=]',xml)
                                $("#producttitle").html("");
                                $("#productdesc").append($desc);
                                $("#producttitle").append($title);

                            });

                        }  

<product productid="1">
    <title>Active Directory</title>
    <status>noinfo</status>
    <description>
        Headline
        <b>tester</b>
        <ul>
            <li>test list element</li>
        </ul>
    </description>
    <link title=""></link>
</product>
```

Cheers,
Terry

Comment: Well basically the usual jquery.ajax $.ajax({ type: "GET",
      url: "product.xml",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: function (xml) {.... I get the value with var $desc = $(this).find("description").text();

Answer (score 1):

<s>To get content with tags included as tags rather than escaped as text content, use `html`:</s>

```js
var $desc = $(this).find("description").html();
```

However, if you are inserting this content into the document, you don't need to get the HTML -- you can just append the selection:

```
$(this).find('description').clone().appendTo('#containingElement');
```

`clone` is necessary to import the node.

Comment: unfortunately using .html() won't work with ajax datatype xml.

Comment: @Terry Thanks, I've deleted that bit.

Answer (score 1):

try to read xml file as html:

$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'file.xml',
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(xml) { ....

Comment: Using the 'HTML' datatype (instead of 'XML') helped solved a problem where the JQuery XML parser failed due to unsupported special char encodings contained in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Just using $(this).find("description").html() seems to work.